# A tutor could not figure out why this small code is giving so many errors, please assist

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, templates

I am looking for what's wrong in this custom double linkedlist homework assignment. It is not finished because I haven't sorted out the errors. I went through this code line by line with my tutor and he says it's correct, yet it displays errors.

We've tried viewing the whitespace, changing public to private + vice versa, adding/removing semicolons throughout the code, checking the text encoding. I don't need help with the actual linkedlist itself, just why I'm getting all these errors.

We must use nested class and must all be in one file The errors I am getting vary from 0 - 40 in number.

[image: screenshot]

```
#pragma once

#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
//#include "Node.h"
//#include "Iterator.h"

template <typename T>
class DoublyLinkedList <T>
{
public:
    class Node
    {
    private:
        T data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;

    public:
        Node(const T & d, Node * p = nullptr, Node * n = nullptr) : data(d), next(n), prev(p) {}

    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    class Iterator
    {
    private:
        Node *current;
        bool reversed;

    public:
        Iterator(Node * n = head, bool rev = false) : current(n), reversed(rev) {}

        Iterator& operator--()
        {
            if (reversed)
                current = current->next;
            else
                current = current->prev;

            return *this;
        }

        Iterator& operator++()
        {
            if (reversed)
            {
                current = current->prev;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        const T& operator *() const
        {
            return *current;
        }

        bool operator!=(const Iterator& other) const
        {
            return (this->current != other->current);
        }

        bool operator==(const Iterator& other) const
        {
            return (this->current == other->current);
        }

        Iterator begin()
        {
            current = head;
        }

        Iterator end()
        {
            current = tail;
        }

        Iterator rbegin()
        {
            current = tail;
        }

        Iterator rend()
        {
            current = head;
        }
    };

    DoublyLinkedList():head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
    {

    }

    //
    DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList& other)
    {
        for (auto x : other)
            push_back(x);
    }

    //
    DoublyLinkedList(initializer_list<T> & list)
    {

    }

    size_t size() const noexcept
    {
        for (size_t length = 0, iterator iter = iterator::begin(); iter != nullptr; ++iter, ++length) { return length; }
    }


    void push_back(const T& value)
    {
        Node * newLast = new Node(value, nullptr, tail);
        tail = newLast;
    }

    void erase(Iterator iter)
    {
        delete * iter;
    }

    void remove(const T& val)
    {
        Iterator iter = Iterator::begin();
        while (*iter != nullptr)
        {
            if (*iter == val)
                delete *iter;
            else
                ++iter;
        }
    }
    //
    void insert(Iterator iter, const T& value)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: First of all, lose the `<T>` in `class DoublyLinkedList <T>`

Comment: Next, `Node * n = head` can't use `head` as a default without knowing which instance of `DoublyLinkedList` to use.

Comment: `initializer_list<T>` needs to be namespaced correctly: `std::initializer_list<T>`

Comment: In `for (size_t length = 0, iterator iter = iterator::begin(); iter != nullptr; ++iter, ++length )`, `iterator iter` should probably be `Iterator iter`. `iterator::begin()` probably should just be `begin()`. This statement is a mess, anyway.

Comment: `begin`, `end`, `rbegin` and `rend` don't return anything.

Comment: Must be a pretty average tutor...  Get a new one.

Comment: Wait a sec. `begin` et al are inside `Iterator`. Think about that for a minute. You have to have an `Iterator` to get an `Iterator`. That will work in the Bizzarro universe. Maybe.

Comment: Below average, @LukePark . I hope.

Comment: Thank you user4581301  for your help.

Comment: Recommendation for the future: write less before trying to compile. Write an empty class. Make sure it builds cleanly and runs correctly. Write a simple constructor. Build and test. Write one function. Build and test. This sounds slow, but reduces the number of things that can go wrong and presents a much smaller amount of code to examine for errors on each iteration. The end result is huge gains in debugging time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about removing `<T>` at the end of `class DoublyLinkedList <T>` ?

Comment: This isn't an answer as it's currently written. It's a comment (*How about trying this?*). If you intend to post an answer, please [edit] to do so. Answers are definitive (*Do this because*) rather than suggestive (*Did you try?* or *How about?*).

Comment: Also only gets its toes wet. OP's code doesn't compile for many reasons.

Answer (score 2):

```
class DoublyLinkedList <T>
                    // ^^^
```

is wrong in the class declaration. Just omit the `<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
class DoublyLinkedList // <<<<< No <T> 
{
   // ...
};
```